# Simple Set with only "contains" method

Tags: java, string, collections

Im looking for a simple Set in Java that *only* provides the following functionality.

```
Set.add(String s);
Set.contains(String s);
```

There is not need for me to retrieve any element of the set. All I want to do is to check if a String is contained in it. Is there such a data structure in Java?

EDIT: I know that I could use a Set implementation like HashSet, etc... But I want a minimalistic data structure with only the two methods listed above.

EDIT2: Im on a memory constrained system that's why.

Comment: HashSet<String> seems suitable.

Comment: Do you want a set that specifically does not support any other operations? It seems like a strange thing to want.

Comment: HashSet will not allow storing same string multiple times.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, exactly. I want a minimalistic data structure. Why waste resources?

Comment: Having extra methods isn't going to waste resources.

Comment: @user2357112: It will take up space man! A lot of space!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`HashSet<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), which have both [`add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add%28E%29), [`contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) functionality, but it won't allow duplicate

Comment: The emphasis is on *only*, I dont want a full blown Set implementation. See comments to question.

Comment: @Roland: Dropping the other methods isn't going to let you make the set more lightweight. What's your actual goal here? Are you on a memory-constrained system?

Comment: Yep, memory constrained system.

Comment: @Roland: Then ask about how to optimize the memory usage of your `Set<String>`s. Can you accept a small false positive rate? If so, a [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can `extends` the `HashSet` class and change on its behavior.

```
public class CustomHashSet<String> extends HashSet<String> {

    @Override
    public boolean add(String e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this, you're violating LSP.  It would be much better to just roll your own interface and have the implementation backed by a Set

Answer (score 0):

If you only use this feature locally, just use a `HashSet` and stick to the non-writing - if you need this functionality application-wide, write an own class backed by a `HashSet`.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want a set that only offers an `add` and a `contains` method, then ... define it!

```
interface MinimalisticSet<T> {
    void add(T element);
    boolean contains(Object object);
}
```

An implementation with a backing `java.util.Set` will be rather simple.

Comment: Then you have to specify your requirements more clearly. You could implement this interface, for example, with a backing array, which would involve the minimal memory overhead. But then, add/contains would no longer be O(1) but O(n)

Comment: No. All that is needed is a simple hash table but without storing the object. Just check if the hash already exists.

Comment: Two objects may have the same `hashCode()` although they are not equal according to `equals(...)`. You *have* to store the object in order to make sure that `contains` works properly. (You have to store the object, or some description of the object that is sufficient for testing for equality - but the `hashCode` in general is *not* sufficient for this!)

Comment: Hash collisions are possible but extremely(astronomically) unlikely. Consider that Git uses the same strategy.

Comment: Even a good implementation of the (32bit!) `hashCode` in Java is in *no* way comparable to the (256bit) SHA used by GIT. For example, the Strings `"aaa"` and `"abB"` already have the same hashCode, namely 96321. (Apart from that, it's (not optimal but) perfectly feasible to implement the `hashCode` method as `return 0;`)